# Detect if a change occur in observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

Does anyone have idea, if it's possible to detect whenever a change occur inside observableArray while using ko mapping, this mean without having to create the model by hand?

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([])
var data = ko.mapping.fromJS(result)
self.items.push(data);
```

I would like to log any changes occurred in any property inside my array of objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to use `subscribe` on the observable to get that information.

See the bottom of this page for more info:

[**Explicitly subscribing to observables**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables)

Answer (score -3):

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([])   
self.item.subscribe(function(context){  
//Comment if there is any changes in the observable array this function will get trigger and changed date ma get in context   

});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?